# Why doesn't Travis CI run "npm install" with NODE_ENV production

Tags: javascript, travis-ci

I tried to compile my project in Travis CI with the following config:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - 0.12
env:
  global:
    - NODE_ENV=production
before_install:
  # - npm run init
before_script:
  # - bower install
  # - gulp
  # - npm install
script:
  - npm install -g bower
  - npm install -g gulp
  - gulp
  - npm run lint
sudo: false
```

If I set in my config

```
- NODE_ENV=production
```

Then Travis CI will compile my project.

Comment: What? I dont see a question in the body here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Travis CI does run `npm install` automatically — I suspect the problem you're having is with `NODE_ENV` and `dependencies` and `devDependencies`.

If `NODE_ENV=production`, NPM will not install `devDependencies` (as noted here: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/6803). You need to make sure the dependencies you need are in the correct group:

- `NODE_ENV=production`: dependencies installed from `dependencies` group
- `NODE_ENV=development`: dependencies installed from `devDependencies` group